# Google maps javascript works fine in web browser but throws error while running in cordova

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

This was working fine for a year but suddenly started throwing errors.
Here is the error we are receiving:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Bw.entries is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at js?v=3&key=&language=en&libraries=places&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:34
    at js?v=3&key=&language=en&libraries=places&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:166
    at js?v=3&key=&language=en&libraries=places&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:167
    at Array.<anonymous> (js?v=3&key=&language=en&libraries=places&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:166)
    at Lfa.Ta (js?v=3&key=&language=en&libraries=places&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:271)
    at Tg.Ta (js?v=3&key=&language=en&libraries=places&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:270)
    at wea (js?v=3&key=&language=en&libraries=places&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:235)
    at Fea (js?v=3&key=&language=en&libraries=places&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:237)
    at Object.google.maps.Load (js?v=3&key=&language=en&libraries=places&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:14)
    at js?v=3&key=&language=en&libraries=places&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:402
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a library issue.

I tried the older version of the library, and it worked.

The working version is: 3.53